# HTML: white space around elements, how to remove?

Tags: image, html, width, whitespace

My webpage contains several divs. Some are set to width: 100%, so they fill the whole page width.
But at the top of the page there is a small whitespace before the first element shows up. Moreover, that same whitespace is visible left and right from elements spanning the whole page width.

I cannot figure out why. If I set:

```
html, body {
width: 100%;
}
```

then the whitespace remains but the page is just stretched out to fit the image width of a div.

Can anyone help? It's probably pretty simple but I must be overlooking something.
Thank you.

EDIT: I must mention I'm using a parallax element. This uses a padding, so the image does fills the whole div and does not leave a black area on top. The HTML is:

```
<div class="js-background-1 container">
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.container { 
    padding-top: 200px;
}

.js-background-1 { 
    background: transparent url(url/to/image) center 0 no-repeat;
}
```

And the javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var $window = $(window); 
var velocity = 0.4;
function update(){ 
    var pos = $window.scrollTop(); 

    $('.container').each(function() { 
        var $element = $(this); 
        var height = $element.height(); 

        $(this).css('backgroundPosition', '50% ' + Math.round((height - pos) * velocity) + 'px');
    });
}; 

$window.bind('scroll', update);

</script>
```

I used the tutorial from http://www.webdesign.org/how-to-create-a-parallax-scrolling-website.22336.html, so there is where it is from. I changed the HTML a bit for my website, but the rest is the same.

I saw the comment about the margin and padding set to 0, but that leads to my div to have a blank space if you don't scroll far enough.

Comment: Can you replicate the problem on JsFiddle.net? Please also post your HTML and CSS here, in your question.

Comment: I updated my question, to include the code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must remove the margin on `body`:

```
body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

You can also remove padding and margin on `html` and `body`

```
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

[**See it on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lj9F4/)

But I would **not advise** to use `*` (the universal selector)

```
* {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This would remove padding and margins on **all** elements.

Comment: Yes! I set padding and margin on html and body and that worked like a charm. Padding inside the div stayed, but the whitespace around is gone. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The good method is to always use at the begining of the file (I forgot to metion this):

```
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

This two line's at the begining of main CSS file fix many problem's that you can encounter.
Hope it'll help you.

Comment: Beware this would remove padding an margins on all elements.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but (and I know I mentioned it to late) I use a parallax element that needs the padding inside. Changing * to 'html, body' did the trick.

Comment: would this override the margin and padding on a `div` class?

Answer (score 0):

```
padding-bottom: 20px;
border: 1px solid red !important;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 100%;
```

Comment: Try this, put this on the body then adjust overlapping contents. After fixing it, remove this line on the body:  border: 1px solid red !important;